# Makefile compiles all files, even though changes are done in a single c++ file

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I work on project involving large number of `c++` files. I am asking this question out of curiosity.

Usually after a `make` is done, a particular `c++` file under modification would be compiled alone for subsequent `make`s. Sometimes I experience even a small modification in single `c++` file results compilation of nearly all the other `c++` files and the final executable.

What is the reason for `Makefile` to compile other non-modified `c++` files?

Comment: Target dependencies. Consider running make on *just* that target, then running a test make to see why all your other files are suddenly out of compliance with their rules. Without seeing the makefile, anything else is going pure speculation.

Comment: My clear plastic ball that I use as a cheap alternative says that it's probably line 17, 43 or 68 in your makefile that is wrong. But then my plastic ball is not right very often, so I wouldn't take too much notice. It is probably better if you post your makefile - or even better, make a simple version of it (but ensure it still exhibits the same problem) and then post that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm quite jealous. My plastic ball is usually quite foggy; a real bastard to get anything out of. Your's being clear makes me feel sad =(

Comment: My own plastic ball told me that I need caching and MySQL an I can be like Google, just better.

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed. But you'll be hard pressed to top your comment yesterday in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476152/bypass-virtual-template-functions-to-achieve-wished-result#comment27157983_18476152) for *years* to come.

Comment: Another common cause for this type of thing is time stamp skew and NFS.  If your system clock is off it can cause `make` to think that source files are newer than generated files and rebuild things unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here comes the concept of `timestamping` in `makefile`. Say for example `make` rule is like this

```
output: dep1
     rule-1
dep1: dep2
     rule-2
```

When you execute the `makefile` then `make` first checks the `timestamp` of `output` file, (if `output` file doesn't exists then by default the rule is executed). say `output` was created at 1200hrs and you change the file dep1 at 1205hrs and execute the `make`, then `make` finds that the target output is older than its depepndency `dep1` so it will execute the rule-1. If suppose `output` is created at 1300hrs, `dep1` at 1230hrs, and now you update the `dep2` at 1310hrs, and execute the `make`. You can see here since `dep1` is older than `dep2` rule-2 is executed and `dep1`'s timestamp has been changed, `output` is now older than `dep1` so rule-1 is executed. You can see here even though `output` doesn't directly depend on `dep2` it is rebuilt when you updated `dep2`

This is what happening in your case. Check the `makefile` and try to check the dependency of the file you edited. The targets which depend on your edited file will be rebuilt.